# Angular error StaticInjectorError CdkConnectedOverlay overlay

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay

starting the environment with the command `ng serve` everything works without errors, but doing a test with the command `ng serve --aot` or `ng serve --prod` (simulating the production version) comes out this error when you open the modal:

[image: Error]

This is my app.module.ts:

https://codeshare.io/5PKywo

I did a lot of research but I still have not found a solution.

---

I solved.

The problem was that the version of this graphic component was not updated (ng-zorro-antd), now I've updated it to the latest version and it works without errors.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: what is OverlayModule? you need to provide Overlay service in OverlayModule.

Comment: I had seen an issue on git that someone had solved in that way

Comment: which issue? post your related module please.

Comment: The issue is when open the modal from an invoke event from service.
between today and tomorrow I check the code better and I try to give more informations

Comment: @Riccardo Please consider posting the error in the question itself so that its readability is easier for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved.

The problem was that the version of this graphic component was not updated (ng-zorro-antd), now I've updated it to the latest version and it works without errors.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I am facing the same problem (zorro w/ cdk giving `No provider` error on AOT). Could you please elaborate what versions you matched?

Comment: Reference for others: https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/issues/3727

Answer (score 0):

Remove `OVERLAY_PROVIDERS` from providers. It's deprecated. Only use `OverlayModule` in imports.